# How to Export a Table to Excel File at Client Side with JQuery?

Tags: jquery, export-to-excel

I use java, jQuery and jsp at my web application. I want to learn that how can I import the values at my table to Excel file with JQuery `at client side`. There are many examples and suggestions even at stackoverflow.com but I saw the solutions as server side as like Apache POI or something like that.

There is a datable plug-in: http://www.datatables.net/ at that plug-in it can be done to export the table data into a excel file I think at client side and so I am searching for a solution as like that.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't export easily yo CSV and MS Excel or any speadsheet appliation can parse the .csv file?

Here is a link for a jQuery Plugin called  [HTML Table to CSV](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/tableToCSV)

Here an example of the plugin: http://www.kunalbabre.com/projects/table2CSV.php

Comment: This plugin export to comma separated values in a webpage and not as excel as asked by the author of the question

Comment: I was proposing an alternative solution because I don't an accurate answer for export xsl file.
Do you have an answer for the question?

Answer (score 0):

Use this VBScript for the client side export. Remember that you need to allow to run activex controls in the browser settings.

```
<script language="vbscript">

Function Export(objToExport) 

    ON ERROR RESUME NEXT 
    DIM sHTML, oExcel, fso, filePath 

    sHTML = document.all(objToExport).outerHTML 

    SET fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
    filePath = fso.GetSpecialFolder(2) & "\MyExportedExcel.xls" 
    fso.CreateTextFile(filePath).Write(sHTML) 

    DIM i 
    SET i = 0 

    DO WHILE err.number > 0 
        err.Clear() 
        filePath = fso.GetSpecialFolder(2) & "\MyExportedExcel" & i & ".xls" 

        i = i + 1 
    LOOP 

    SET oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application") 
    IF err.number>0 OR oExcel = NULL THEN 
        msgbox("You need to have Excel Installed and Active-X Components Enabled on your System.") 
        Exit Function 
    END IF 

    oExcel.Workbooks.open(filePath) 
    oExcel.Workbooks(1).WorkSheets(1).Name = "My Excel Data" 
    oExcel.Visible = true 
    Set fso = Nothing 

End Function
```